# useLocation not detecting location change from MemoryRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

I have this React component that depends on props and the query params to render:

```
const Module = ({ color = 'green' }) => {
  const location = useLocation()

  let name = 'Pear'
  const matchedStr = location.search.match(/name=[a-zA-Z]+/)
  if (matchedStr){
    name = matchedStr.split('=')[1]
  }

  return <div id="Module">{`${name} is ${color}`}</div>
}
```

I am trying to write a test to check that the component reacts to both prop changes and query param changes.

```
/* react-testing-libray setup */

test('Module responses to both prop change and query param change', () => {
  const screen = render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/?name=Banana"]}>
      <Module color="yellow" />
    </MemoryRouter>
  )

  expect(screen.getByText('Banana is yellow')).toBeInTheDocument() // this passes

  screen.rerender(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/?name=Apple"]}>
      <Module color="red" />
    </MemoryRouter>
   
  )

  expect(screen.getByText('Apple is red')).toBeInTheDocument() // this fails
})
```

I cannot figure out how to get the component to observe location change from the React-Router hook.  The text always comes out as "Banana is red"

Some packages information:

- react 17.0.2
- react-router-dom: 6.14.2
- react-testing-library 12.1.5

I've tried the following approaches and none of them worked:

1. Use `Routes` and `Route` components to render Module instead.
2. use `useSearhParams` hook instead of `useLocation`
3. mess with `initialEntries` pro of `MemoryRouter`.

The query param name seems to get frozen in time to be "Banana", as long as I rerender the current screen.  It'd be fine if I render a new screen instead.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to unit test here? If I had to hazard a guess I'd say you should initiate a navigation action from `"/?name=banana"` to `"/name=apple"` and wait for the UI to rerender instead of trying to jack the entire ReactTree with another router "instance". This doesn't happen like this in your actual app when it's running, right? When using RTL the tests should follow as closely as you intend the components to be used in real life, e.g interacted with by a user or other components.

Comment: I could initiate a navigation action but that would only update the URL, so that's only half the battle.  In the real app instance, what happens is that the component detects query param change, calls an API to get data specific to that param as prop ... I wanted to simulate both the query param change and prop change.

Comment: The component is rerendering, even without the `Routes` and `Route` wrapping.  I am just trying to keep this unit-ish-test small.  I could instead write an integration test ... either way, it would be good to understand, why this other MemoryRouter Instance still gets the previous router's config

Answer (score 1):

The test should effect a navigation change from the initial `"/?name=Banana"` URL path/searchParams to the next `"/?name=Apple"` URL path/searchParams.

Use a `HistoryRouter` and custom `history` object so you can effect a navigation action within the test(s).

Example:

Module.test.jsx

```
import { render, act } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history"; // <-- history@5

import Module from "./Module";

const history = createMemoryHistory({
  initialEntries: ["/?name=Banana"]
});

test("Module responses to both prop change and query param change", () => {
  const screen = render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Module color="yellow" />
    </Router>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("Banana is yellow")).toBeInTheDocument();

  // Navigate to new path with new search params
  act(() => {
    history.push("/?name=Apple");
  });

  screen.rerender(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Module color="red" />
    </Router>
  );

  expect(screen.getByText("Apple is red")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

### Demo

[image: Edit uselocation-not-detecting-location-change-from-memoryrouter]

[image]

FWIW, there's improvement to be made in your `Module` component as well with regards to reading the `name` value from the URL searchParams. Use the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-search-params) hook to read them instead of trying to string/REGEX process the `location.search` string.

Example:

```
import { useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Module = ({ color = "green" }) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const name = searchParams.get("name");

  return <div id="Module">{`${name} is ${color}`}</div>;
};

export default Module;
```